# How I can update fullcalendar options from odoo calendar controller

Tags: odoo-16

In odoo **web** module I found **CalendarCommonRenderer** in his setup method, they get instance of **fullcalendar**

```
export class CalendarCommonRenderer extends Component {
    setup() {
        this.fc = useFullCalendar("fullCalendar", this.options);
        this.click = useClickHandler(this.onClick, this.onDblClick);
        this.popover = useCalendarPopover(this.constructor.components.Popover);
        this.onWindowResizeDebounced = useDebounced(this.onWindowResize, 200);

        useEffect(() => {
            this.updateSize();
        });

        useEffect(
            (view) => {
                this.env.config.setDisplayName(`${this.props.displayName} (${view.title})`);
            },
            () => [this.fc.api.view]
        );
    }
```

and **this.options** are options  for fullcalendar instance parameter, like this:

```
get options() {
        return {
            allDaySlot: this.props.model.hasAllDaySlot,
            allDayText: this.env._t("All day"),
            columnHeaderFormat: this.env.isSmall
                ? SHORT_SCALE_TO_HEADER_FORMAT[this.props.model.scale]
                : SCALE_TO_HEADER_FORMAT[this.props.model.scale],
            dateClick: this.onDateClick,
            dayRender: this.onDayRender,
            defaultDate: this.props.model.date.toISO(),
            defaultView: SCALE_TO_FC_VIEW[this.props.model.scale],
            dir: localization.direction,
            droppable: true,
            editable: this.props.model.canEdit,
            eventClick: this.onEventClick,
            eventDragStart: this.onEventDragStart,
            eventDrop: this.onEventDrop,
            eventLimit: this.props.model.eventLimit,
            eventLimitClick: this.onEventLimitClick,
            eventMouseEnter: this.onEventMouseEnter,
            eventMouseLeave: this.onEventMouseLeave,
            eventRender: this.onEventRender,
            eventResizableFromStart: true,
            eventResize: this.onEventResize,
            eventResizeStart: this.onEventResizeStart,
            events: (_, successCb) => successCb(this.mapRecordsToEvents()),
            firstDay: this.props.model.firstDayOfWeek % 7,
            header: false,
            height: "parent",
            locale: luxon.Settings.defaultLocale,
            longPressDelay: 500,
            navLinks: false,
            nowIndicator: true,
            plugins: ["dayGrid", "interaction", "timeGrid", "luxon"],
            select: this.onSelect,
            selectAllow: this.isSelectionAllowed,
            selectMinDistance: 5, // needed to not trigger select when click
            selectMirror: true,
            selectable: this.props.model.canCreate,
            slotLabelFormat: is24HourFormat() ? HOUR_FORMATS[24] : HOUR_FORMATS[12],
            snapDuration: { minutes: 15 },
            timeZone: luxon.Settings.defaultZone.name,
            unselectAuto: false,
            weekLabel:
                this.props.model.scale === "month" && this.env.isSmall ? "" : this.env._t("Week"),
            weekNumberCalculation: "ISO",
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekNumbersWithinDays: !this.env.isSmall,
            windowResize: this.onWindowResizeDebounced,
        };
    }
```

and **CalendarCommonRenderer** is a subcomponent of **CalendarRenderer** to determine if is **week**, **day** calendar. In registry they add **calendarView**, like bellow:

```
export const calendarView = {
    type: "calendar",

    display_name: "Calendar",
    icon: "fa fa-calendar",
    multiRecord: true,
    searchMenuTypes: ["filter", "favorite"],

    ArchParser: CalendarArchParser,
    Controller: CalendarController,
    Model: CalendarModel,
    Renderer: CalendarRenderer,

    buttonTemplate: "web.CalendarController.controlButtons",

    props: (props, view) => {
        const { ArchParser } = view;
        const { arch, relatedModels, resModel } = props;
        const archInfo = new ArchParser().parse(arch, relatedModels, resModel);
        return {
            ...props,
            Model: view.Model,
            Renderer: view.Renderer,
            buttonTemplate: view.buttonTemplate,
            archInfo,
        };
    },
};

registry.category("views").add("calendar", calendarView);
```

Now, I want to update from **CalendarController** the fullcalendar options or re.render the fullcalendar with new options.

ATT.: in my code I have inhertance for **CalendarController**, **CalendarModel**, **CalendarRenderer** and **CalendarCommonRenderer**

I can Update fullcalendar options or re-render with new options from **CalendarModel**, **CalendarRenderer** or **CalendarController**?

Comment: Do you need to change the option in `CalendarCommonRenderer`?

Comment: I would want to update option of fullcalendar instance, but from CalendarController @Kenly

Comment: @kenly I fix it, go to my answer you will see how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix from **CalendarModel** component.
CalendarCommonRender and CalendarController they share CalendarModel instance.

Go to CalendarModel (inheritance) and create a new setter and getter:

In your setup() override add:

```
this.fc_api = null;
```

Create setter and getter:

```
set fcApi(api){
  this.fc_api = api;
}
get fcApi(){
 return this.fc_api;
}
```

Now, in your **CalendarCommonRender** (inheritance) component add in setup() override:

```
mounted( () =>{
  this.props.model.fcApi(this.fc);
})
```

Go to **CalendarController** (inheritance) component override

Where you need call (in my case I am calling in setup() override):

```
mounted( ()=>{
  this.midel.fcApi.setOption("minTime": "09:00:00");
});
```

Now you can update **fullcalendar** option where you need in **CalendarController**, but only after component completely mounted

Comment: You can simply override the options add `minTime` and `maxTime` options in the common calendar rederer

Comment: Yeah, but I was to be done from another component (CalendarController)